# PHPMailer and CC Addresses on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, email, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails from the server and it's been working well. We've recently moved the website from Windows Server 2012 to Mac OS X 10.10.

I'm having trouble getting the CC recipients to work now that it's running on Mac OS X.

I add the CC recipients from an array:

```
foreach($ccRecipients as $ccRecipient)
{
    $mail->AddCC($ccRecipient);
}
```

The email is being sent but no CC addresses are included - it appears that they are somehow being converted into BCC addresses as they emails are delivered to the CC addresses but they are not listed in the CC address section.. Looking at the PHPMailer docs for the AddCC function it mentions that "Note: this function works with the SMTP mailer on win32, not with the "mail" mailer". I gather this means it won't work on OS X?

If that is true is there any way I can work around this and still include CC email addresses with PHPMailer on OS X? Here's some simplified code that sends an email:

```
 require('inc/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');     
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();

 $mail->AddAddress('bill@acme.com');
 $mail->AddCC('sally@company.com');

 $emailSubject = 'Testing PHP Mailer';
 $emailBody = 'Quick manual test of the PHP Mailer';

 $mail->From = 'sales@widgets.com';
 $mail->FromName = 'Acme Widgets';

 $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject = $emailSubject;
 $mail->Body    = $emailBody;

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
 $sendEmailError  = 'There was an error sending the status email: '. $mail-     >ErrorInfo;
 echo $sendEmailError;
 } else {
 $sendEmailError = '';  
 }
```

Comment: add complete send mail code

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help that you've based your code on an obsolete example and are using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

As far as PHPMailer is concerned, OS X is pretty much identical to Linux and has none of the limitations that Windows does (why would you think win32 applies to OS X?), and it includes the postfix SMTP server by default.

There is no particular limitation on OS X for using CC addresses. If you read the documentation, you'll see that you can set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` to see the SMTP conversation.